# Asm Assembler - CX loop never executes

Tags: loops, assembly, dos, x86-16

I have a vector and I have to put in the `AX` register the sum of the numbers that are greater than 50 ( > 50 ).

I do not understand why my loop does not work when I run it. First it compares 100 with 50, jumps at *adunare* , add 100 to `AX` but then it exits the loop and terminates the program.

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 10h
.DATA
vect DB 100,70,3,10,60,200,30
len DB 7
.CODE

begin:
    mov ax,@DATA
    mov ds,ax
    mov ax,0
    mov cl,len
    mov ch,0
    mov si, -1

bucla:
    inc si
    cmp vect[si],50
    ja adunare
    jb mic

adunare:
    add ax, word ptr vect[si]

mic:
    loop bucla
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h

END begin
```

Comment: Your vector is bytes but you add words. That's unrelated to the problem though. I suspect you are using your debugger wrong, it probably does loop back just that it's not shown for you. Make sure you use the single step feature.

Comment: To add bytes to a word register, you can use an intermediate register like this: `xor dx, dx --- mov dl, byte ptr vect[si] --- add ax, dx`.

Comment: thanks it works fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> .STACK 10h
> ```

With such a small stack the debugger could very well terminate your program as soon as an interrupt occurs, leaving you thinking that the loop doesn't execute.
Specify a larger stack. 256 bytes is a reasonable minimum.

> ```
> adunare:
>     add ax, word ptr vect[si]
> ```

To add the **byte** at `vect[si]` to the **word** in `AX`, you have several options:

- using an intermediate register [like zx485 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56006716/asm-assembler-cx-loop-never-executes#comment98659308_56006716)

  - clearing the extra register:

    ```
    xor     dx, dx
    mov     dl, vect[si]
    add     ax, dx
    ```
  - extending from byte to word in one instruction:

    ```
    movzx   dx, vect[si]
    add     ax, dx
    ```
- without an extra register but using a cascaded addition:

  ```
  add     al, vect[si]
  adc     ah, 0
  ```

> ```
>     cmp vect[si],50
>     ja adunare
>     jb mic
> adunare:
>     add ax, word ptr vect[si]
> mic:
>     loop bucla
> ```

You can write this simpler and if the number 50 were present in the array, it would erroneously be added to the sum. Besides the *above* and *below* conditions there's also the *equal* condition to take care of.

```
    cmp     vect[si], 50
    jna     mic
    add     al, vect[si]
    adc     ah, 0
mic:
    loop    bucla
```

For perfection you could dismiss the `loop` instruction (it has a reputation for being slow) and use instead `dec cx` `jnz bucla`. This in turn gives you the opportunity to not having to zero `CH` and rather use `dec cl` `jnz bucla`.

Everything together:

```
    xor     ax, ax      ; This makes AX=0
    mov     cl, len
    mov     si, -1
bucla:
    inc     si
    cmp     vect[si], 50
    jna     mic
    add     al, vect[si]
    adc     ah, 0
mic:
    dec     cl
    jnz     bucla
    mov     ah, 4ch     ; DOS.Terminate (exitcode is in AL)
    int     21h
```

I've tested a good number of variations.
This is a faster version of the loop:

```
    xor     ax, ax      ; This makes AX=0
    xor     si, si
    mov     cl, len
bucla:
    cmp     vect[si], 50
    jna     mic
    xor     dx, dx
    mov     dl, vect[si]
    add     ax, dx
mic:
    inc     si
    dec     cl
    jnz     bucla
```